# Picker problems on Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms application using a picker as below. On Windows it works fine but on Android the picker items are displayed multiple times when trying to select an item. I have noticed that this started to happen when I changed the Android target from Android 7 to Android 8. Has anyone also experienced this problem? Is a fix/work around available?

Thanks
Paul.

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewExInspection" 
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ExInspectionDetail}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="0,0,15,1">
                                <Label FontSize="Small" Text="{Binding InspectionSection}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                <Label FontSize="Small" Text="{Binding InspectionText}" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label FontSize="Small" Text="Status" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                <Picker x:Name="PkStatus" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"
                                                SelectedIndex="{Binding InspectionStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                IsEnabled="{Binding StatusEnabled}">
                                    <Picker.ItemsSource>
                                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                        <x:String>Incomplete</x:String>
                                        <x:String>Pass</x:String>
                                        <x:String>Fail</x:String>
                                        <x:String>N/A</x:String>
                                        </x:Array>
                                    </Picker.ItemsSource>
                                </Picker>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: as per your code it's working perfect. share the full code

Comment: Pratius Dubey - It seems to be an Android 7/8 issue. Works great on Android 7 but not on Android 8. I don't know how to work around the issue.

Comment: Did you try parsing picker's itemsSource from ViewModel just to check if you also meet this error in that case ?

Comment: Umar3x, Yes I tried setting the itemsSource via the ViewModel but it still behaved the same.